# how to get relative url from absolute url in django view?

Tags: django, absolute-path, relative-url

Is there a handy function that converts absolute url to relative url in django?
Preferably, it would return the absolute url if base url doesn't actually match.

Comment: do you mean the other way round ? Because `get_absolute_url` gives you a relative URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) to get the relative `path` from the absolute uri. The following snippet is using `urlparse` from [`six`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) so that it works both under PY2 and PY3.

```
def get_relative_url(absolute_uri):
    from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse
    return urlparse(absolute_uri).path
```